# MySQLi not returning fetched data

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP script that queries the database and returns a list of all the usernames in my database. Problem is, it is not printing anything and I think I am doing the while statement incorrectly, this is my code below:

```
<?php
    include "init.php";

    $stmt = "SELECT username FROM tbl_users ";
    $result = $dbcon -> prepare($stmt);
    $result->execute();
    $result->store_result();
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($row['username']=="Ben"{
          echo "Here";
        }
        //$count++;
    }

?>
```

Even something as basic as this doesn't work:

```
<?php
    include "init.php";

    $stmt = "SELECT username FROM tbl_users ";
    $result = $dbcon -> prepare($stmt);
    $result->execute();
    $result->store_result();
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo "Here";
        //$count++;
    }

?>
```

I can't also seem to increment the count too and it is not even printing the basic "Here"

Comment: Are you sure the user that connects to the database has permissions to view that table? Are you sure the table has records in it? You could try "SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_users" because that should return a single row (assuming there are no errors).

Comment: Do you have a username `Ben` in the table? You have commented out `count++` without `$`, is it truly `count++` instead of `$count++`?

Comment: hi, ben does exist in the DB

Comment: even without that if statement nothing is being returned

Comment: Why do you need this if and count?

Comment: oh, i was planning to use that count variable after to see if that username exists and to tell them that it is already taken. but even the basic script - the second one doesnt work

Comment: Why do you use oop and procedural style? What is the output of `$result->fetchAll()`?

Comment: @dex `->fetchAll()` is a PDO method, not a MySQLi method. There is [`->fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), but only  if they have `mysqlnd`.

Comment: Hi, sorry how do I do $result->fetchAll()?

Comment: Can you show us your init.php file?

Comment: @Sean he's using PDO methods (see ->prepare() / ->execute()), not MySQLi functions - did i miss something? You can view the results with `var_dump( $result->fetchAll() )`

Comment: @dex [`->prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) / [`->execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) are also MySQLi methods, as well as [`->store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) is only MySQLi. In addition to the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

Comment: remove `$count` before `while statement`

Comment: What do you get if you add `echo $result->num_rows;` right after `$result->store_result();`? Does it give you something other than `0`?

Comment: @Sean so there is something in the database

Comment: I just need to iterate through $result

Comment: Have you tried using [`->fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), ie.  `... $result->execute(); $result->store_result(); $result->bind_result($username); while ($result->fetch()) { echo $username; }`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are not reading manual/examples properly.

mysqli_stmt_get_result() doesn't change the state of a statement. It *returns* a mysqli result. So you have to assign this returned value to a variable and than use this one.

Besides, you are using a database **completely wrong way**. Instead of selecting all rows from database you should always select **the only data you need.**

For your case the code would be like this.

```
include "init.php";
$name = "Ben";

$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM tbl_users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
$stmt->bind_result($found);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();

if ($found) ... // here you go
```

For other cases you have to read the manual or a book carefully. and reproduce the code **exactly**.

Answer (score -1):

Since there are multiple error in your code i managed to write a code **am not sure following is best** but it works

```
<?php
    include "init.php";

    $stmt = "SELECT username FROM tbl_users ";
    $result = mysqli_query($sqlconnection, $stmt) or die($mysqli_load->error);
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($row['username']=="ben"){
          echo "Here";
        }
        //$count++;
    }
?>
```

few errors i found in your code are `)` is missing here `if($row['username']=="Ben"{` next to `"ben"){`

and use this type of connection

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost","user","pass","database");
```